# Why is "to win over" also called "to one up on"?

Tags: differences, idioms

Peter Lynch has a book that's called *One Up On Wall Street*, which probably means "Win Over Wall Street." But why this phrase? Why is it "One Up"? Is there a story behind it? Where does it come from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Win over" and "one up" have different meanings. "One up" is more akin "get ahead" or "outperformed":

> She one-upped me.
>
> Her retort one-upped my joke.
>
> His portfolio one-upped mine.
>
> His portfolio is ahead of mine.
>
> Her portfolio outperforms mine.

"Win over" generally means "convince" or to convert to one's way of thinking:

> His arguments won me over.
>
> Her charm won him over.
>
> They like to win over clients with fancy meals.

Comment: See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-upmanship) for the origin of "One-upmanship."

Comment: I see... my "win over" was to mean... beating it...  such as Peter ran 100M in 12.2 seconds and Tom used only 11.8 seconds... and so Tom won.... over Peter?  (can you say Tom won over Peter?)

Comment: @Jian: Sure. You could say that but it would probably be best to use something else: _Tom beat Peter_; _Tom won against Peter_; _Tom defeated Peter_. "Won over" has such a specific meaning that saying _Tom won over Peter_ could be confusing.

Comment: yeah, in chinese, "win over" kind of makes sense... like we will say: Tom's speed "pass over" Peter's.  but funny, english doesn't use it this way